# sessionStorage returns undefined in one field, but works in other

Tags: javascript, undefined, session-storage

I have this code:

```
// Run on page load
window.onload = function() {

    // If values are not blank, restore them to the fields
    var personal_number = sessionStorage.getItem('personal_number');
    if (personal_number !== undefined){
        $('#personal_number').val(personal_number);
    }

    var email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
    if (email !== undefined){
        $('#username').val(email);
    }

    var password= sessionStorage.getItem('password');
    if (password !== undefined){
        $('#password').val(password);
    }
}

// Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("personal_number", $('#personal_number').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#username').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("password", $('#password').val());
}
```

This "works" if I add a value to `personal_number`, `email` and `password` it gets saved to my sessionStorage and when I refresh the page, my input fields get rightly populated.

**But** when I go to another page (within the same website) and return back, I get `undefined` outputed in `personal_number` input field and the correct values in the others.

I dont understand why!

First, it should not output anything if the value is `undefined` because: `if (personal_number !== undefined)`.

Second, how come only `personal_number` is not working and the two other fields are fine?

**Update:**

I removed password field since cacheing it is insecure.

I have also figured out what is causing the problem, but I have *not* solved it.

When I visit a page with no input fiels and return then, now, all my fields output `undefined`. So it seems like i get a new session when I do so.

But how come it still ouputs `undefined`?

```
(function ($) {
    // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {
        var person_number = sessionStorage.getItem("person_number");
        var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");

        if (person_number !== undefined || person_number !== null ||
            person_number != undefined || person_number != null){
            $('#person_number').val(person_number);
        }
        if (email !== undefined || email !== null || 
            email != undefined || email != null){
            $('#username').val(email);
        }
    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("person_number", $('#person_number').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", $('#username').val());
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I know I am testing for to much, but there is no way this should output `undefined`!!

**Update 2**

I also updated it so it will not save inputs if the input is `undefined`/`null`. But it **still** does not work..

```
(function ($) {
    // Run on page load
    window.onload = function() {
        var person_number = sessionStorage.getItem("person_number");
        var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");

        if (person_number !== undefined || person_number !== null ||
            person_number != undefined || person_number != null){
            $('#person_number').val(person_number);
        }
        if (email !== undefined || email !== null ||
            email != undefined || email != null){
            $('#username').val(email);
        }
    }

    // Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {

        var person_number = $('#person_number').val();
        var email = $('#username').val();

        if (person_number !== undefined || person_number !== null ||
            person_number != undefined || person_number != null){
            sessionStorage.setItem("person_number", person_number);
        }
        if (email !== undefined || email !== null ||
            email != undefined || email != null){
            sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: first you !== undefined does not work, try checking using if(personal_number){...}
Second never store passwords in session.

Comment: @ElieNassif if I have `if(personal_number){...}` I get undefined on all fields on page load, wierd. Maybe it sees undefined as a stored value? Alright, will remove my password field!

Comment: what type is your `input#personnal_number` ?

Comment: @Kaiido A string

Comment: @Kaiido `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="person_number" id="person_number" placeholder="Personnummer" required />`

Comment: ... if it were a number I would have had the why, but here the only guess I can make is that somehow, you are saving an empty string, or restting the valie of this input after. You've got the value when you call directly `localStorage.person_number` in the console?

Comment: @Kaiido I get `undefined` when i call it in console as well.. :(

Comment: For your edit, if all are set to undefined it's probably because when you leave/reload the page, your inputs are empty.

Comment: @Kaiido please see my update again. If i try to reach my page in incognito mode i get a server error. Could this mean something?

Comment: wait you are in incognito ?! That's the purpose of this mode to not store data.

Comment: @Kaiido, No I am not. It was just for testing..

Comment: ok. Then I am clueless... sorry. Does the same happen in different browsers ? What if you use localStorage instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite old and you might have had your answer, by now, but if not, or for any other who's having the same issue :

I think your jquery code is loaded on every page and thus, your onbeforeunload statement tries to store your fields' value on every page, even where the field does not exist and that's when the Items get "undefined".

Before you try to store the value of a field, make sure the field actually exists, using getElementById, for example, like this :

```
var fieldExists = document.getElementById('person_number');

if(fieldExists !== null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('person_number', $('#person_number').val());
}
```

And in your onload, you don't need to test if (person_number !== undefined and so ... only if it's null

```
if (person_number !== null) {
    $('#person_number').val(person_number);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How is this any different from the way i am doing it?

Comment: @vonhact, what you're doing is trying to store the value of your field and it works fine as long as you're on the page your form belongs to, but as soon as you go to another page, (every page your jquery is loaded with), you're trying to store it again as you quit the page, even though your form doesn't exist there and thus you get Undefined.
My proposal is to test whether the field exists or not, before trying to store its value.
By doing this, you won't try to store the value in the pages where the field doesn't exist when unloading.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
sessionStorage.personal_number
```

this will be undefined if not set

you can set values using this:

```
sessionStorage.personal_number = 123456
```

Comment: [There is no difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: @vonhact yes there is. `getItem` returns `null` if the value doesn't exist in localStorage, while accessing the property directly will return `undefined` in this case.

Comment: @Kaiido you are correct. But this does not help me in this case though.

Comment: @vonhact It should since you are doing an `xxx !== undefined` check over something that won't return `undefined` ever, but `null`.

Comment: @Kaiido Even if I am checking for `if(personal_number)` it wont work. Also, how come it works for `email`?